# Unable to create Logging file using Log4Net in C#

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am trying to write a log file using Log4net in C# but the log is getting printed on console.
Here is my code

```
 class Program
{
    public static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
        Log.Debug("TEST");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Here is the XML (log4net.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="mylog.txt"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Once"/>

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout">
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>    
  </root>
</log4net>
```

inside Assembly.cs i have

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

But still the log file isn't create inside debug folder. Does anyone have any idea why this is getting printed on console instead of inside the Log file.

Comment: Do you copy the config file to output directory?

Comment: Thanks @S.Spieker. That was the main cause. I have changed BuildAction="Content" and Copy to output directory="Copy Always"

Comment: @S.Spieker: Write that as an answer and ask OP to accept it for helpin other users.

Answer (score 2):

Do you copy the config file to the output directory?

If you are using Visual Studio, set the Build Action to Copy to output directory="Copy Always" or "Copy if newer" and BuildAction="Content"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the app.config for log4net configuration, I think you should use

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Also, you might need to resolve the log after calling configure

```
public static log4net.ILog Log { get; private set; }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
}
```